# How do I get a variable from a query?

Tags: c#, database, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

Here's my query:

```
       var query = from d in db.Users
                    where user.UserName == d.UserName && user.Password == d.Password
                    select d;
```

Now I know for a fact that the query will either be null (if user credentials do not match) or only return one user. My problem now is that I want to access the variables of that one user. How do do that? I've tried using this line of code:

```
        foreach (var item in query)
        {
            Session["id"] = item.ID;
            Session["name"] = item.UserName;
            Session["type"] = item.Type;
        }
```

But it causes my program to crash (I know the query isn't null so that isn't the issue).

Comment: Crash how? What exception?

Comment: The program itself doesn't crash, more of internet explorer crashes when I run the program.

Comment: Internet Explorer crashing would not be related to anything you are showing us.  I suspect what you are calling internet explorer "crashing" is simply the standard asp.net yellow error screen.  If so, this *would* include a stack trace so long as you're not operating with [custom errors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).  This would be IE just displaying the standard asp.net error page - nothing wrong with IE itself.  You'd see the same in any other browser.

Comment: Let me clarify, by crashing I mean I get a "localhost is not responding".

Comment: @Razer I doubt the code you have posted has anything to do with "localhost is not responding".  Are you able to access anything on localhost? Sometimes that can simply be caused by not having `127.0.0.1 localhost` in your hosts file, or having it commented out in the hosts file (located in `%systemroot%\system32\drivers\etc\`)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use [`SingleOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb342451%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to generally return `null` if the collection is empty, but it can also return something else if `TSource` defines something else as the default, so use with caution.

```
var user = (from d in db.Users
            where user.UserName == d.UserName && user.Password == d.Password
            select d).SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: -1 for not adding supporting information to your answer.

Comment: `query` will never be null because you just assigned it. Your first solution with `.Single()` will still throw an exception. Your second example with `.SingleOrDefault()` will not return a query but rather the element itself.

Comment: @metacubed Sorry, I haven't used this in awhile.  You're right that `Single` throws an exception if the collection is empty, so he's probably better off with `SingleOrDefault` anyway.

Comment: @Namfuak I corrected your sample. Also had to move the link around to get around the 6-char minimum.